Where is my btc?
Hi My friend bought BTC in 2017 on an exchange. He just recently went back into it and saw he had some btc in there. After taking a look we saw he bought some then sent some, problem is he doesnt remember where he would have sent it, is there any way to find out to jog his memory?
11/12/2017
To address 3BPixQAKAXXu34UVmNHVNg5zAU6ZBqbsNQ -
Sent 0.003643-
Tx id d0e02f3946c0c01bf31b4e035490c34a
5/12/2017
To 38tJkbhhgYxx7JjptZFsrynd4PcZWqKd7z -
Sent 0.010564-
Txid 052bac1e036ce1f76e2dbb34e880b085


is there any way to find out to jog his memory?

No.
As you know, Bitcoin transactions are recorded in the Bitcoin blockchain. This is public information, replicated by all Bitcoin nodes.   However Bitcoin is pseudo-anonymous, there is no simple way to identify recipients. In Bitcoin, control over money is associated with numbers that are indistinguishable from random numbers.
Your friend should look into old email messages etc.
